# How to run Node Express server and Angular on the same port?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am new to Node and Angular. I need to know whether is it possible to run a Node Express app serving as a backend and an Angular frontend on the same port. I followed Angular Quickstart tips on angular.io and created a Node todo application but both are running on different port which raises the issue of Cross Origin Request Blocked Issue.

Comment: I would recommend you don't use express or node.js to serve static content (including an AngularJS app).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get Angular and Express running on the same port I've always served my Angular build files by the Express app itself. You should be able to tell Express to serve static content from an Angular build directory like this:

```
app.use(express.static('../accounting-client/dist'));
```

Which would work if you had a file structure like so and were running `serve.js` with Node:

```
-accounting-server
  -serve.js
-accounting-client
  -dist/*
```

You can customize as needed by configuring the Angular build folder to be wherever you need it, or use Grunt/Gulp to move files around to the folders you prefer with a build task.

As mentioned by Yakov this isn't ideal for development since it won't work with the Angular dev server's auto-refresh.

Comment: this runs on local how to deploy it on azure?

Comment: This is working but this restricts me using angular universal as i need to provide static source to nodejs and angular universal run through server folder. Any idea how to use like this way only but also angular universal

Answer (score 12):

To have Node.js serve the Angular app on the same port, your Angular app must be deployed under your Node's directory where the static resources are deployed. But in dev mode, it's more productive to serve your Angular bundles (so they auto-rebuild in memory as you code) from the dev server, e.g. on port 4200, while the Node server runs on another port, e.g. 8080.

To avoid cross-origin issues, you need to configure a simple proxy file in your Angular app to redirect all data requests to your Node server. For example, create a file proxy-conf.json in the root dir of your Angular project:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

This will redirect all requests that have `/api` in the URL to your Node server, assuming that it runs on port 8080. Then start your Angular app using the following command:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy-conf.json
```

An HTTP request in your Angular App can look like this:

```
http.get('/api/products');
```

Of course, you need to configure the `/api/products` endpoint for GET requests on your Node server.

Comment: Very useful! Thanks.

Comment: Hello Yakov, I referred link in the video tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFP0oXNNveg. Can you check it and revert back.

Comment: I added above code by making config file, When I run ng-serve I keep getting following error " constructor(_configPath, schema, configJson, fallbacks = [])"

Comment: copy paste the code from here: https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/blob/master/Angular4/http-node-samples/client/proxy-conf.json

Comment: Very good answer that includes the difficult solution for the cross origin issues.

Comment: hi yakov , after configuring this can app be opened in url - localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you need to have access to your client-side project from within Express project, as [spacefozzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1363414/spacefozzy) said, is true. but you still can keep your projects separated.
To do so, you can create a symlink from your client-side project directory in your Express project directory:

```
// while in Express directory
ln -s ~/path/tp/client-side/build name-in-espress-dir
```

This way you can maintain projects isolated.